# How many Gluster Volumes is allowed in single server

Tags: linux, network-share, glusterfs

I have created one Gluster Volume

```
sudo gluster volume create devshare transport tcp server1:/mnt/test
```

GFS1 in server1 and able to mount the share on server2

```
sudo mount -t glusterfs server1:/devshare
```

but when I tried to create a second volume in server1 and tried to mount in server2 it is not allowing the mount (so a total of two glustervolumes in one server).

I am getting error message `endpoint is not connected`.

Is it allowed to have two glustershare in one server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a limit on how many volumes you can have (not that I know of, and if it is, its pretty high).

The error you are getting `endpoint is not connected` is FUSE's way of telling you its not able to communicate to the other server. This is normally down to a network interruption. [Glusterfs doc here.](http://www.gluster.org/community/documentation/index.php/Transport_endpoint_is_not_connected)

I have in the past unmounted and remounted all shares and it has came back. This is also gluster way of fixing the issue.

I am giving a broad answer, if this is still not fixing the issue I recommend you paste your volumes.

Have a look at `gluster volume info`, make sure you can see volumes on both servers etc.

Comment: We checked the logs and found that the issue is with the network. When mounting the second share the share fuse tries to connect to the port of Servers and it fails. Do we need to specify port for each share or gluster will manage it..?

Comment: Glad you found the issue. You do _not_ need to specify a port. You have to make ensure that TCP ports 111, 24007,24008, 24009-(24009 + number of bricks across all volumes) are open on all Gluster servers. If you will be using NFS, open additional ports 38465 to 38467.

Comment: the ports are open.. I see that both the gluster shares are using same port and combinations.. I am not sure if its allowed to have two gluster shares in same server